# Game development: "Play Now" via website vs. download & install

Tags: java, python, flash

I've spent some time looking over the various threads here on stackoverflow and while I saw a lot of posts and threads regarding various engines that could be used in game development, I haven't seen very much discussion regarding the various platforms that they can be used on.

In particular, I'm talking about browser games vs. desktop games.

I want to develop a simple 3D networked multiplayer game - roughly on the graphics level of Paper Mario and gameplay with roughly the same level of interaction as a hack & slash action/adventure game - and I'm having a hard time deciding what platform I want to target with it. I have some experience with using C++/Ogre3D and Python/Panda3D, but I'm wondering if it's worth it to spend the extra time to learn another language and another engine/toolkit just so that the game can be played in a browser window (I'm looking at jMonkeyEngine right now).

For simple & short games the newgrounds approach (go to the site, click "play now", instant gratification) seems to work well. What about for more complex games? Is there a point where the complexity of a game is enough for people to say "ok, I'm going to download and play that"? Is it worth it to go with engines that are less-mature, have less documentation, have fewer features, and smaller communities* just so that a (possibly?) larger audience can be reached? Does anyone have any experiences with decisions like this?

Thanks!

(* With the exception of flash-based engines it seems like most of the other approaches have these downsides when compared to what is available for desktop-based environments. I'd go with flash, but I'm worried that flash's 3D capabilities aren't mature enough right now to do what I want easily).

Comment: " I haven't seen very much discussion regarding the various platforms that they can be used on." --> Possibly because such questions belong more on [gamedev](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) than here.

Comment: Whoop, that could be why. I'll have a look over there yonder.

Answer (score 1):

Download and install is a harder sell.  People are more reluctant to do it, and once they have done it, you own the problem of platform compatibility, and you have installed code to update or avoid as your game evolves.

Java applets eliminate all that mess.   Presumably also flash or html5.